# cordova printer plugin for windows 8 application

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, windows-8, cordova-plugins

I'm developing Windows 8 application which is packaged with cordova. I need to print my html document via connecting to a printer with bluetooth/wireless. I have researched and could not find any printer plugin which is working in cordova application. I found some plugins but all of them for IOS or Android. I have restricted time, so i can not write printer plugin myself. If anyone can help, I would be appreciated.